# Maven plugin to operate at parent and child module levels?

Tags: java, spring, maven, plugins

I have a large multi-module java/maven application where each child module is it's own java application and the root parent pom defines the standard dependencies

```
pom.xml - parent pom
- child1/pom.xml - app1
- child2/pom.xml - app2
```

I plan to write a custom maven plugin, which will be configured at sub-module level, which will configure the java application for this module. I'd hope to have commands such as

```
myapp:start-app
myapp:stop-app
```

I also want the same plugin to operate at the parent pom level, where the supported options would relate to the cluster of applications

```
myapp:start-cluster
myapp:stop-cluster
```

It is reasonable to have these 4 commands in one plugin or should i split the commands into two separate plugins each with a specific concern? I've seen the 'spring-boot:run' maven plugin but it doesn't support operations at the cluster level.

Any advise would be appreciated?